# Manually adding Windows 7 to Kali Grub List

Tags: windows, kali-linux, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I recently installed Kali Linux on my windows 7 computer with the intention of being able to double boot. When I installed Kali, I had to install it in UEFI mode, because that was the only thing that worked. Upon booting the GRUB loader shows, but only Kali is on the list. I have tried various things to fix this, but nothing works. I was able to add an entry to the list by adding this to /etc/grub.d/40_custom:

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
chainloader +1
}
```

However I was unable to boot into it when selecting it from the menu. I got an error like "no UEFI found" or "invalid UEFI" or something like that.

If I do `sudo update-grub` or `sudo update-grub next` this is the output:

```
root@kali:~# sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-kali1-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0-kali1-amd64
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

I also tried doing `sudo grub-install /dev/sda1`, but then I got this output:

```
root@kali:~# sudo grub-install /dev/sda1
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
GUID Partition Table Header signature is wrong: 0 != 5452415020494645
GUID Partition Table Header signature is wrong: 0 != 5452415020494645
GUID Partition Table Header signature is wrong: 0 != 5452415020494645
GUID Partition Table Header signature is wrong: 0 != 5452415020494645
GUID Partition Table Header signature is wrong: 0 != 5452415020494645
GUID Partition Table Header signature is wrong: 0 != 5452415020494645
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

I am wondering if windows 7 even supports UEFI at all, if it does, do anyone know how I can add it to the GRUB list?

I mounted `/dev/sda1` to see what was there and I didn't find any .efi file. I found a file called `bootmgr` and copied it to /boot/efi/EFI and tried to boot from it by using the BIOS, but that didn't work. Maybe the issue is that I don't have an EFI file to boot windows from? If this is the case, how can I create one?

`sudo parted -l` outputs:

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ACF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  368MB  367MB   primary   ntfs
 2      368MB   393GB  392GB   primary   ntfs
 3      393GB   495GB  102GB   extended
 5      393GB   393GB  299MB   logical   ext4
 6      403GB   473GB  70.0GB  logical   ext4
 9      473GB   493GB  20.0GB  logical   ext4
 7      493GB   495GB  1999MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 8      495GB   495GB  199MB   logical   fat32           boot, esp
```

Comment: Can you show `sudo parted -l` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue here was that Grub and Kali was installed in UEFI mode, while Windows 7 was installed in BIOS/Legacy mode.

Additionally, I think the Windows bootloader was installed to the entire disk, and was completely overwritten under installation of Kali.

For anyone with this issue, I do not think it is supposed to be possible to boot a BIOS/Legacy system from UEFI Grub, and you might want to check that the Windows bootloader still exists at all.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should type update-grub next...
If you can't do that, then here is some tips for you.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/418666/update-grub-command-not-found